# Entity Framework n-Tier

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, dto

I am utilizing the Entity Framework in order to interface with some WCF services and some MVC3 websites I have built. I am using a database first approach.

What I have created is a library that has a Data, Model, and CRUD folder. Data contains the edmx file and a partial class for my Entities that creates a ToDTO() method. The Model contains a class of each of my entities that I can pass around as an object. The CRUD contains what should be expected - common read, update and delete methods.

My entities are named in the fashion of 'StudentEntity', and my DTO have a simpler name such as 'Student'. So the StudentEntity class has a method ToDTO which returns a Student object.

And my CRUD folder has a class with name Student that contains the CRUD operations for the student entities.

The confusion seems to come when I have another deleloper look over the code, they get confused on which Student they are looking at, the entity, the DTO, or the CRUD class.

How should I change my naming scheme to make it more understandable? Also can you give me any suggestions on cleaning it up a bit. Maybe I do not need the DTO classes and can somehow use extension/reflection to not have a separate class for each ToDTO method.

Comment: The confusion stems from the fact you have 2 or more classes that represent the same data and are thus almost-but-not-quite-identical. I'd say you have to swallow that cost to keep an n-tier architecture. I'd definitely rename the CRUD classes to something like `StudentRepository` or at least `Students` though.

Comment: For your CRUD class, you could use the name of StudentDAC for Student Data Access Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to keep that same architecture, I would use the following naming conventions:

```
// Namespaces & folders
// /DTO   (Data Transfer Objects classes only)  
// /Model (edmx files and utility classes)  
// /Data  (Repositories)
// /Services (Specialized repositories and business logic classes)

// Naming conventions
StudentDTO // (Data Transfer Object)
Student    // (the entity itself)
StudentRepository // (very common and conventional name)
StudentService    // (common and conventional name)
```

My 2 cents,
Sincerely,
Max

Comment: I'd also add in a `StudentBO` in a Business object library that handles all the logic/crud/validation. Use it to link the `StudentDTO` to the `Student` entity and call the repository classes from here.

Comment: I'd call that a `Service` e.g. `StudentService` which handle the business logic.

Comment: You seem to be heading in the right direction for what I am looking for.I understand what you say to put into the DTO, are you suggesting the StudentSErvice contain all the CRUD operations for the Student? And Model is the edmx and the partial class of all entities? The Repository then is what I am confused on. What is that holding?

Comment: The `Repository` is for `CRUD` only. The `Service` will enforce business logic and manipulate `DTOs` or `Models` (more likely `DTOs`), validation, etc... A typical `Service` method will take a `DTO` as a parameter and return the result of a calculation e.g. `double StudentService.GetFinalMark(StudentDTO student)`. This way, it can be easily unit tested.

Comment: When entering that dimension, it is worth checking out `Dependency Injection` frameworks such as *StructureMap*, `Unit Testing` frameworks such as *NUnit* and reading on the `Repository Pattern` and the `Decorator Pattern`. It's a big step up in software architecture and imo, it is worth the effort. You don't necessarily need to apply those patterns but to know about them and debate them is one of those *nice to have*.